# Delete duplicate tuples with same elements in nested list Python

Tags: python-2.7, duplicates

I have a list of tuples and I need to delete tuples containing same elements.

d=[(1,0),(2,3),(3,2),(0,1)]

OutputRequired=[(1,0),(2,3)]   Order of output doesn't matter

command set() doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), edit your question and retag your question. At least the programming language you want to use ought to be tagged.

Comment: This answer has a neat solution, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850892/delete-duplicate-tuples-independent-of-order-with-same-elements-in-generator-pyt?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this solution, I am copying each of the tuples into a `temp` after checking whether it is already present in the `temp` and then copy back to  `d`.

```
d = [(1,0),(2,3),(3,2),(0,1)]
temp = []
for a,b in d :
    if (a,b) not in temp and (b,a) not in temp: #to check for the duplicate tuples
        temp.append((a,b))
d = temp * 1 #copy temp to d
```

This will give the output as expected.

Comment: Wouldn't this be too slow in really big lists? Is there any faster alternative?