# Delete duplicate tuples independent of order with same elements in generator Python 3.5

Tags: python, tuples, generator, python-3.5

I have a generator of tuples and I need to delete tuples containing same elements. I need this output for iterating.

```
Input = ((1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3))

Output= ((1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3))
```

Order of output doesn't matter.

I have checked this question but it is about lists: [Delete duplicate tuples with same elements in nested list Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702664/delete-duplicate-tuples-with-same-elements-in-nested-list-python)

I use generators to achieve fastest results as the data is very large.

Comment: Why are you using tuples if order doesn't matter?

Comment: ^^ exactly. You'd be better off with a `frozenset`

Comment: These are combinations that I check the max value from with abs(1,3)

Comment: What is your criteria for "containing same elements". I can remove (3,1) because (1,3) is there but I still come up with `(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)` for your example.

Comment: There can be only one (pun intended) combination of a pair. So only one pair should be conserved, no matter if it is (3,1) or (1,3) if it contains the same integers.

Comment: So, given your example input, is my output or your output correct?

Comment: You should use variable names other than `Input` and `Output`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can normalize the data by sorting it, then add it to a set to remove duplicates

```
>>> Input = ((1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3))
>>> Output = set(tuple(sorted(t)) for t in Input)
>>> Output
{(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 1), (3, 3)}
```